# PayuMoney integration in react JS

Tags: reactjs, payumoney

I am using windows.bolt.launch() to show payumoney overlay
getting the following error even before initializing the payment.

GET https://sboxcheckout-static.citruspay.com/bolt/css/bolt_2_8.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
catch block :
Error in adding payment

Comment: I am facing this same issue, using vue js

Comment: I contact to help desk they were really helpful. And make sure ur hash string is perfect

Comment: I solved this error by passing proper data, so that it will give you a proper hash.